# python paramiko execute script on remote host and log output in backgroound

Tags: python, paramiko

From a python script I want to execute a script on a remote host but not wait for the script to finsh, at the same time I would like to log output of the remote script execution on localhost

so far I have

```
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(keyfile)
ssh  = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting ... "
ssh.connect(ip, username='testuser',key_filename=keyfile, timeout=10)
print "connected..."
commands = "sudo -S -p '' %s" % commands
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(commands+' 1>&2' , get_pty=True)
print("reading outputs from the remote command")
for l in stdout :
    print("stdout : %s" % l.strip())
for l in stderr:
    print("stderr : %s" % l.strip())
```

this shows the output of the remote script execution in the console
I would like the pyton script to run the remote script and then exit while still logging the output of the remote script execution on localhost

Comment: Could you just `python /your/paramiko-script.py > /some/log/file 2>&1 &`?

Comment: yeah thats what I ended up doing 
thanx